# Not able to import package from an external jars on Hue notebook(scala interpreter)

Tags: scala, interpreter, hue

I could able to configure notebook and can run scala programs. Now I want to use some classes from external jars, and when I do import package, it couldn’t find the corresponding jars.
I am not sure how to add jar in classpath from hue notebook hue web UI. I tried to find the solution on blog and hue documentation there is nothing mentioned about it.

I have tried to set the `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` in spark-defaults to point to some random directory on hdfs like, I used `hdfs:///tmp/spark/*` for both the configurations in `spark-defaults.xml`. Then I added the corresponding jars to that directory on Hdfs for example, I have kept `aaa.jar` in `hdfs:///tmp/spark/aaa.jar`.

Then I wrote on HUE notebook (scala interpreter)

```
from aaa import org.barboliled._
```

and execute it. It throws an error.